# how to create a while true loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

let me start off by saying, that i am a BEGINNER to coding. i use python 3.4.GUI.

so i've got this code:

```
register = input("have you registered an 
account?")
if register == "yes":
    print("you may proceed to log in")
if register == "no":
    print("please, create an account")
else:
    print("that is not a valid answer")
```

how to i create a while true loop on this so that if the user enters anything other than "yes" or "no", they get taken back to the start?
thanks!

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in `while True:`.

Comment: use `elif` instead of multiple `if`s

Comment: Looks like this has been answered before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498557/input-prompt-within-a-while-true-loop

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment break if you want to end the loop after correct input.

```
while True:
    register = input("have you registered an account?")
    if register == "yes":
        print("you may proceed to log in")
        # break?
    elif register == "no":
        print("please, create an account")
        # break?
    else:
        print("that is not a valid answer")
```